# Finding Jan 1st of current year in HQL

Tags: python, date, hql

I have a python function that passes in a HQL query into a database and I need to use hive to find (currentYear)-01-01

```
def foo():
    return " SELECT variables \
        FROM bar \
        WHERE \
        fizz = buzz \
        AND to_date(somedate) > date_format(current_date,'yyyy-01-01') "
```

The last line is currently not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah embarrassing, this works exactly as it is supposed to.

```
to_date(somedate) > date_format(current_date,'yyyy-01-01')
```